# Selenium Python Configure Jenkins to run build. My build fails

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to configure Jenkins to build my Selenium Webdriver Python code.
When i click Build Now it fails
The Console output shows the following:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\ClearCore
[ClearCore] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson6133135491793466847.bat

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\ClearCore>copy E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases\*.py 
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\ClearCore>python smoketests.py 
python: can't open file 'smoketests.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\ClearCore>exit 2 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher 'Publish JUnit test result report' failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

In PyCharm i have a smoketests.py file as follows:

```
    import unittest
from xmlrunner import xmlrunner
from TestCases.LoginPage_TestCase import LoginPage_TestCase
from TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase import AdministrationPage_TestCase
from TestCases.DataConfigurationPage_TestCase import DataConfigurationPage_TestCase

login_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPage_TestCase)
admin_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(AdministrationPage_TestCase)
dataconf_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(DataConfigurationPage_TestCase)

smoke_tests = unittest.TestSuite([login_tests, admin_tests, dataconf_tests])

xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(verbosity=2, output='test-reports').run(smoke_tests)
```

I have a test_HTMLRunner.py as follows:

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
import os
from TestCases.LoginPage_TestCase import LoginPage_TestCase
from TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase import AdministrationPage_TestCase
from TestCases.DataConfigurationPage_TestCase import DataConfigurationPage_TestCase

# get the directory path to output report file
result_dir = os.getcwd()

login_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPage_TestCase)
admin_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(AdministrationPage_TestCase)
dataconf_tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(DataConfigurationPage_TestCase)

smoke_tests = unittest.TestSuite([login_tests, admin_tests, dataconf_tests])

# open the report file
outfile = open(result_dir + "\TestReport.html", "w")

# configure HTMLTestRunner options
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                                       title='Test Report',
                                       description='LADEMO create a basic project test')

# run the suite using HTMLTestRunner
runner.run(smoke_tests)
```

I have a suite.py as follows:

```
    import sys
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
import os
import unittest
import AdministrationPage_TestCase
import LoginPage_TestCase
import DataConfigurationPage_TestCase

class Test_Suite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main(self):

        # suite of TestCases
        self.suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        self.suite.addTests([
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPage_TestCase.LoginPage_TestCase),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(AdministrationPage_TestCase.AdministrationPage_TestCase),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(DataConfigurationPage_TestCase.DataConfigurationPage_TestCase),            
            ])
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
        runner.run (self.suite)

import unittest
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In Jenkins I have configured the following:

From the section Build, Execute Windows Batch Command

```
copy E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases\*.py
python smoketests.py
```

From the section Post-Build Actions, Publish JUnit test result report

```
test_reports/*..xml
```

Below test_reports/*..xml it shows:

```
    ‘test_reports/*..xml’ doesn’t match anything: even ‘test_reports’ doesn’t exist
```

How do i get this to work please?  What am i doing wrong?
Is there any sample demo I could follow and then I can get my setup to work?
Thanks,

Riaz

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be in the copy step of you batch file.  Notice how it says it cant find the file.  Surround the source and destination paths with double quotes so that windows knows your path has spaces in it.

It also appears the copy operation doesn't have a destination specified.  You <strike>should</strike> may want to specify that too.  Although apparently that isn't a requirement, as I just found out :).

Once the copy operation succeeds, check the workspace directory to see if the file(s) you expect are present.

Alternatively, you can tell the Jenkins job to use a custom workspace, the directory where your tests live.  With this configuration you don't even have to worry about copying files.

Here's how:

In the job config in Jenkins, open the ***Advanced Project Options*** and select ***use custom workspace*** and set the directory to `E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases\`.
Then the build command can just be `python smoketests.py`.

Comment: I added double quotes around E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases\*.py  The files gets copied now.

Comment: I get the error at  C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\ClearCore\workspace>python smoketests.py 
python: can't open file 'smoketests.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Should i put the full path to smoketests.py?

Comment: Is smoketests.py in the Jenkins workspace directory?

Comment: It is in the following path: E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases\smoketests.py

Comment: The copy operation should have also created a copy of it in C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\ClearCore, can you confirm?

Comment: The copy operation didn't copy smoketests.py into the workspace directory.  I am going to try use custom workspace which you suggested above.

Comment: In Advanced project settings I ticked use custom workspace, specify directory as "E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases"  In Execute windows Batch command i enter python smoketests.py  I build it, the error now is Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases"
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\"E:\RL Fusion\projects\Jenkins sample\ClearCore501\TestCases"